# Getting JIRA project image with JQL

Tags: php, curl, jira, jql

I'm using JQL to query issues from JIRA, and storing them in a json file somewhere. There's one thing I can't seem to figure out:

In the `project` fields, they've made project avatars available. However, they're only the URLs of the avatar. So I'm storing away these URLs in a json file, but when I render these json objects in HTML later, the images obviously won't display in the browser (since the images are secured and you have to be logged in to view the images).

I have also tried to display the images by directly querying them at runtime (was hoping the API authentication would be valid for displaying the images), but that doesn't work either.

Anyone understand what's going on?.